# MySQL/MariaDB delay data flush for frequently updated table table > 5 billion rows

Tags: mysql, mariadb, percona

I have table with 5 billion rows where the same row(rows) can be updated multiple times per minute.
How to configure MySQL/MariaDB with data flush delay?
In order to save disk I/O I want mysql delay data flush from buffer to disk(data, undo, redo) let's say once per 5 minute.

I can handle data loss in case of interrupted power and so on.

Comment: Please as4k database admin related questions on the dedicated DBA sister site of SO, not on the programming focused SO!

Comment: You want to minimize I/O and you don't mind data loss in case of a power loss? Sounds like you should use a cache, not a database.

Flushing modified pages in InnoDB is handled automatically. You can use a few options to influence it, but only slightly. InnoDB will still flush as much as it can every second.